# Binding Parent View DataContext to DataTemplate Child View DataContexts

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, datatemplateselector

I've been experimenting with WPF, Xaml, MVVM, and DependencyInjection lately. Consequently, I am creating a UI using MVVM principles. A certain portion of the UI is designed to act like a wizard wherein not all of the available options are presented to the user at the same time. Each section of options is its own View (sub-View) with a single View (Parent View) hosting these sub-Views in a ContentControl. The user sets certain options and uses buttons to move from one section to the other.

**View Navigation**

To switch between these views I'm using a DataTemplateSelector with each sub-View defined as a DataTemplate in my Xaml resources.

Content Control in the Main View:

```
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ParentViewControl, Path=ViewState, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" />
```

Example sub-View Data Template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SubViewATemplate">
        <local:SubViewAView x:Name="SVAView" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ParentViewControl, Path=DataContext}" ViewState="{Binding ElementName=ParentViewControl, Path=ViewState, Mode=TwoWay }" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

On the Parent View and each sub-View I've created a Dependency Property called ViewState (an enum). These bind to each other through the DataTemplates. In each View's code-behind I update this ViewState Property based off user input and it propagates up to the Parent View which in turn triggers the DataTemplateSelector. So far, so good. The navigation works beautifully.

**ViewModel Info**

The Parent View has a ViewModel which implements INotifyPropertyChanged as its DataContext. I'm attempting to use this single ViewModel to bind Properties to the Parent View and the sub-Views. The problem is the DataContext binding in the DataTemplate snippet above does not work. (Which is odd to me since the ViewState binding does.) After various attempts to get this to work, the DataContext on a sub-View is either null or the ViewState control variable.

I am currently using the UnityContainer as my dependency injector.

**Various Attempts**

Here are the various other things I've tried that have all failed:

1) Registered the ViewModel as a singleton in the UnityContainer thereby using Constructor Injection on the sub-Views to set the DataContext. (Does not work because there must be a Parameter-less Constructor for the DataTemplate resource.)

2) Registered the ViewModel as a singleton in the UnityContainer and then using Property Injection on the sub-Views to set the DataContext. (Does not work. I think this is due to the UnityContainer not working when an object is instantiated in Xaml.)

3) Creating sub-ViewModels for each sub-View that needs a ViewModel to display properties that would have existed on the Parent ViewModel. I've used this before to get around the Xaml instantiation problem with the UnityContainer. I then replace the DataContext binding in the DataTemplate with the associated sub-ViewModel. (Does not work because for some reason the DataContext of my Parent View is getting set to the ViewState variable instead of remaining my ViewModel which I've set in the view's Constructor. This in turn means the sub-ViewModel property on my Parent ViewModel can't be found to bind to the DataContext of the sub-View.) Are the Content and DataContext of UserControls the same thing? Does setting one affect the other?

4) Moving the ViewState dependency property from the View to the ViewModel and then setting the ContentControl's Content to bind to the ViewModel. This violates MVVM principles but by this time I was trying anything to get this to work. (It doesn't work because when ViewState is changed in the code-behind of the view the ViewModel does not trigger as changed.) I haven't gone any further with this one because I didn't want to go deeper violating MVVM.

**Conclusion**

I've found most of these attempted solutions on this site over the last couple days. I haven't had any formal training in WPF, Xaml, and MVVM so I suspect I'm missing something obvious, or am attempting to do something that isn't possible. I'm going to keep attempting variations on the above and researching until I find something that works, but I thought I would tap into the collective knowledge here to help me find a solution.

What I'd prefer is to have the group of Views use the single ViewModel as their DataContext so I can bind properties to their controls. And have the Views' navigation be controlled by a DataTemplateSelector. Is there a way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had similar issues before, I have had good luck using a RelativeSource binding. Maybe try something like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContentControl},Path=DataContext}"
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the response!. I tried something similar:
`Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyBindingProperty, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type  UserControl}}}"
`

which did not work, but your suggestion does! Thank you very much. I wonder if I named the ContentControl and used it's name for ElementName, if that would work, too. That way I don't have to rely on the visual tree. I'll give it a shot and respond.

Comment: My experiment worked. I named my ContentControl from above "ViewArea" and used:

`DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ViewArea, Path=DataContext, Mode=TwoWay}"`

as the binding in the DataTemplate. So both of these can work.
I'd seen both of these syntax examples before but did not know which control I would find the DataContext in. Something small, but so critical. Thanks, again @trippedOverXaml

Comment: I am glad it helped, and I am definitely going to try your experiment soon as well! Thanks for the update :D (Edited because I can't seem to spell)